# how to : Background image should remain static but the webpage on it must scroll down in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css, web

I need to this for my website.
Background image should remain static but the webpage on it must scroll down in asp.net

`<head runat="server"> <title></title>`

```
   <style type="text/css"> 
    body { background-image: url('~/saibaba.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center; 
    background-attachment: fixed; } 
    #form2 { font-weight: 700; }
     </style>
     </head>
```

this is my code still not working

Answer (score 1):

`body { background-attachment: fixed; }`

Comment: <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-image: url('~/saibaba.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #form2
        {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
    </style>
</head>
this is my code still not working.

Answer (score 0):

for alternative ways of putting background images on, check out Chris Coyiers full screen images

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

tried to separate your CSS code from your main page. Put all CSS  code on .css file which can be called in your main page. Try this code -->>

```
background-image:url('path_of_file_be_sure');
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center
```